# my card class keeps getting a compiler error c1001

Tags: c++

here is the header

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Card {
friend class deck;
friend class Hand;
private:

// assigns ranks to a string to greatly shorten the necessary array
const string ourRanks[13] = { "2", "3", "4",
    "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack",
    "Queen", "King", "Ace" };

//  assigns suits to a string to greatly shorten the necessary array
const string ourSuits[5] = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };


// stores the rank
int rank;

// stores the suit
int suit;

// card, stores string card for usage
string card;


public:


Card() {
    this -> rank = 0;
    this -> suit = 0;
    this -> card = "The Two of clubs";
    return;
}


// Card constructor
Card(int ranks, int suits);


// gets rank and suit
int getRank(int ranks);
int getSuit(int suits);


// defines the value
int getValue();


// gets the highest and lowest values
int getHighValue();
int getLowValue();


// finds and declares the rank and suit
bool validRank(int ranks);
bool validSuit(int suits);


// creates a card

 bool equals();


// exports the card to be used
string newCard();

// These create the numerical representation of the card ranks
const int TWO = 0;
const int THREE = 1;
const int FOUR = 2;
const int FIVE = 3;
const int SIX = 4;
const int SEVEN = 5;
const int EIGHT = 6;
const int NINE = 7;
const int TEN = 8;
const int JACK = 9;
const int QUEEN = 10;
const int KING = 11;
const int ACE = 12;


// These create the numerical representation of the card suits
const int CLUB = 0;
const int DIAMONDS = 1;
const int HEARTS = 2;
const int SPADES = 3;

 };

  #endif
```

Here is the cpp file

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <ios>
  #include <cmath>
  #include <string>
  #include <assert.h>
  #include <stdio.h>


  using namespace std;

  #include "Card.h"


  Card::Card(int ranks, int suits) {

  this -> rank = getRank(ranks);
  this -> suit = getSuit(suits);
  assert(validSuit(suits));
  assert(validRank(ranks));
  this->card = newCard();
  return;

  }




  int Card :: getRank(int ranks) {
  rank = ranks;
  return  rank;
  }


  int Card :: getSuit(int suits) {
  suit = suits;
  return suit;

   }


  int Card ::getValue() {
  if (rank == TWO) {
    return 2;
  }
  else if (rank == THREE) {
    return 3;
  }
  else if (rank == FOUR) {
    return 4;
  }
  else if (rank == FIVE) {
    return 5;
  }
  else if (rank == SIX) {
    return 6;
  }
   else if (rank == SEVEN) {
    return 7;
  }
  else if (rank == EIGHT) {
    return 8;
  }
  else if (rank == NINE) {
    return 9;
  }
  else if (rank == TEN) {
    return 10;
  }
  else if (rank > TEN && rank != ACE) {
    return 10;
  }
  else {
    return -1;
  }
  }


  int Card ::getHighValue() {
  int high = getValue();


   if (high == -1) {
    return 11;
   }
   else {
    return high;
    }
    }



    int Card ::getLowValue() {
    int low = getValue();
    if (low == -1) {
    return 1;
    }
    else {
    return low;
    }
    }


    bool Card ::validRank(int ranks) {
    if ((TWO <= ranks) && (ACE >= ranks)) {
    return true;
    }

    else {
    return false;
    }
    }


     bool Card ::validSuit(int suits) {
     if ((CLUB <= suit) && (SPADES >= suits)) {
     return true;
     }
     else {
     return false;
     }
     }

     bool Card :: equals() {
     Card otherCard(rank, suit);
     if ((suit == otherCard.suit) && (rank == otherCard.rank)) {


     return true;
     }
     else {
     return false;
     }
     }

     string Card::newCard() {
     card = ourRanks[getRank(rank)];
     card.append(" of ");
     card.append(ourSuits[getSuit(suit)]);
     return  card;
     }
```

Here is the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C1001   An internal error has occurred in the compiler. {Project4}  c:\users\thelazyogre\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\{project4}\card.cpp  23
```

Comment: What's your C++ version?

Comment: No, I mean if you use C++11, C++14, C++17, C++93, whatever.

Comment: Are you refering to the microsoft Visual studio version xx.x cause in that case 14.0

Comment: Jesus, I mean the C++ iteration. :P These ones standardized by ISO and all, you know what I mean? They were called C++0x, C++1y or C++1z for example before standardization. But I guess using the information you gave I can figure it out on my own.

Comment: Wait do you mean compiler version, I just ran a working  file through the command prompt And it said optimizing compiler version 19.0

Comment: What's the 5th suit?  You declare the array to have 5 strings, so what is the 5th suit? (Most of my decks only have 4, but you may have different cards).

Comment: Yeah, if you're trying to troll people and still seeking help you're not going to get far. If you weren't kidding with me: **heck no**, I don't mean that.

Comment: Why are you calling a member function to return a member data and not accessing the member data directly:  `this -> rank = getRank(ranks);`.  Also, isn't it redundant?

Comment: a mistake, I put that there to accommodate the null space that is  required for char array, which I confused with the string array, Thank you that compiler error is gone, so sorry for wasting your time

Comment: No I wasn't trolling, I was trying to lessen you work because I genuinely don't know what you were asking for and had no idea where to look but I was asking you take time out of your day to help me out so I figured I should at least try to help

Comment: The code is hurting my brain. Here's a replacement:  `int GetValue() { return min(rank, TEN) + 2;}`.

Comment: The method `newCard` is poorly named because it doesn't return or create a new card.  A better name would be `toString` or `annotate`.

Comment: Evil code:  member name same as class name (insensitive compare).  Most coding guidelines say that class name identifiers should be different than member names, other than case.   Perhaps using `description` or `name` for the member name.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time, I figured out the problem, It is working as it needs to now, I used to many Initializations for my array I fixed it by readjusting it's parameter's

Answer (score 0):

It's a compiler bug. I tried the same code in VS2015 and received the message:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: scratch, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  scratch.cpp
1>E:\Code\VS2015\scratch\scratch\scratch.cpp : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 246)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

As pointed out in the answer by Patrick Duggin and the comments it is related to the array initialisation. My minimal reproducible is as follows:

```
#include <string>

class X
{
    std::string strings[2] = { "first" };
};

int main()
{
    X x;
}
```

The above code produces the same error. This is valid C++ code. Adjusting the array size, or adding another initialiser to the array is a workaround for the bug.

I could not reproduce the bug using an array of a different type. I don't have the motivation to find out exactly what it is about `std::string` that causes this.